# Taking photos "simply" does not work

Tags: android, android-camera

Adding file path extra to image capture intent causes camera app to malfunction on TF300t Android tablet with stock system version 4.2.1. Pressing "done" button does nothing - not even closing camera app activity. No result is returned.

The code I'm using was extracted from [Adroid developers site](http://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics.html)

```
Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File imageFile = createImageFile();
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, THIS_CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

With **createImageFile()** defined as:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    File outputDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();

    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "photo_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File image = new File(outputDir, imageFileName);

    return image;
}
```

When line

```
cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(imageFile));
```

is removed, camera app acts as expected.

Is there any resonable workaround ? I would rather not build a camera app myself just to take a photo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problematic line:

```
File outputDir = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
```

I've replaced it with:

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "1mind_" + timeStamp + ".jpg";
    File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),  imageFileName);
    return photo;
}
```

Turns out, image has to be stored on external storage not in cache dir.

Comment: Ran into the same problem. Very deceiving bug with no error message. I was trying to save the photo directly to my application's private storage and that's a no-no. Thanks for your post.

Comment: For me with Android v.10 it didn't work when I was accessing the photo from WebView. Started to work fine with the following:
File photo = new File(AppContext.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), imageFileName);
as getExternalStorageDirectory is now deprecated.